# Program executes even with warning in php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a php code where I just query to insert rows into table via POST method every thing happens fine with WARNING ,I couldn't figure out why is that a warning message

**WARNING MESSAGE IS:**
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a266/public_html/poster.php on line 9

**CODE IS:**

```
include "db.php";
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb1 (col1,col2) VALUES ('$_val1', '$_val2')");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
$result="inserted";
```

NOTE :Value is perfectly inserted into table and returns "inserted" message But why is that warning..?

Comment: you have `mysql_fetch_assoc` without any select query.

Comment: What are you trying to *fetch* from an INSERT query to begin with?!

Comment: What can I use instead I am a beginner

Comment: try to print error using die(mysql_error());

Comment: Found the error since I am not fetching any data after inserting I should use   mysql_query ($sql); in my program this solved...lesson learned..thankyou

Answer (score 1):

INSERT just returns true or false.There is no result to fetch with INSERT query.

Comment: You are right I made mistake in fetching..I coded as mysql_query ($sql);  this solved the warning..thankyou